# Will the noise level change with battery chemistry?

Tags: batteries, filter, noise, motor-controller, battery-chemistry

I'm using a 48V motor controller and a 48V battery. When I check the 48V terminal with an oscilloscope, it seems noisy. The battery chemistry is LiFePO4. If I use NMC type battery, can I reduce the noise level?

Comment: Can you describe *exactly* how you perform the measurement, what you see, and what you expect to see? I seriously doubt that your scope is capable of measuring the voltage noise of a battery...

Comment: I understand from reading a PhD thesis on a low noise DAC project, that the lowest noise voltage reference the author had found in the 0.01Hz (IIRC, might have been a decade in frequency either way) region and upwards was a lead acid battery at 50% SOC, using a buried zener at lower frequencies. Given a choice between motor and battery as noise suspects, I'd choose the motor every time. Some battery chemistries, and indeed constructions, might have lower internal impedance, suppressing the motor noise better than others.

Comment: Most likely the motor controller is the noise source.  LFP has a pretty low impedance per cell, so changing battery chemistry is unlikely to do anything. You could add decoupling to reduce the noise somewhat. But, why is it a problem? Explain what problem you are hoping to solve (including the noise spectrum) and you may get better answers.

Comment: What type of motor?  What type of motor controller?  What is happening when you see noise?  Does noise go away when motor is NOT being driven?

Answer (score 1):

Most batteries are impressively quiet when not loaded and really good when loaded with constant load.

Batteries do have their own noise just like anything else, but i doubt you are interested in it in the context of motor controllers.

On the other hand, their internal impedance can respond to a variable load (or charge current) in a rather complex way, depending on the frequencies involved, state of charge and other factors.

Keep in mind that the internal impedance of a battery is neither linear (it tends to rise with current), nor completely active (the chemical processes inside have their finite characteristic times that manifest as capacitances and inductances when one tries to model them).

In regard to their impedance for a given energy capacity, LiFePO4 are rather good.

You can, of course, always double the battery capacity and halve the noise, but this solution doesn't scale well.

In general, the AC noise from the load doesn't do any harm to the battery. On the other hand, I have seen at least one case when it heated the battery substantially. A reasonable bank of capacitors improved both the overal efficiency as well as the battery temperature.

What to do if the load is noisy and the noise at the battery terminals bothers you?

- Use low-ESR capacitors. Of course. A complete CLC filter may be needed in some marginal use cases.
- Protect the noise-sensitive circuit instead. It is usually low-power and can be protected from the noisy power with much less effort.